# Is it possible to wrap a table around another table (or any float/text/minipage)?

Tags: tables, floats, longtable, wrapfigure, wrap

Is it possible to wrap a table around another table (or any float/text/minipage)? I.e. the table width is adjusted so another thing indents the table. Imagine text wrapping a float, but instead of text I want a table wrapping another element.

You might question: why not simply put the table after the other element? To answer that, I'll describe what I'm trying to do.

EDIT: added drawing. Note the green lines are the row separators, green for contrast with the blue pen I used. Note the drawing was made on squared paper.
[image]

The element I'm trying to put aside of my long table is tall but not wide (e.g. a figure of 15×3cm²). It cannot be reshaped, to make it fit the width of the page nicely. The table I'm trying to deform is one to two pages long. It has untitled columns, but the contents speak for themselves, so it does not matter if one (or some or all) of the columns are widened where the wrapping ends and widens the table. The table width is the entire text area. I have no text in the document, I only have the tall element to put neatly next to a long table. Also, all table rows are separated by a line, so I think the line between the last row next to and the first row after the tall element should be the full width of the table, not the reduced width.

I have tried to do this myself by adding an additional column to the table, in which I put the tall element. However, since I don't know how tall and wide it is going to be (it can change, its contents are different for different document versions), I don't know where to end this column and to continue the long table with N-1 columns (using `\multirow` and `\multicolumn`). I don't know beforehand how many long table rows fit next to the tall element and I don't know how wide the tall element will be, so I don't know how to continue the N-1 columns after the wrap ends.

Another option is to put the tall element in the margin, but I'm using a very small margin and the tall element might be 10×5cm², which would leave a lot of white space (we're trying to minimise white space here).

Can you give me an example of a long table wrapping around a tall different element? I think a solution would be to "fool" the table by reducing `\textwidth` by the width of the tall element plus some separation (plus optional glue). However, I wouldn't know how to do this.

Any other clever solutions are welcome! I don't mind splitting my long table into two pieces, as long as they look continuous (i.e. vertically non-separated) and the width, height and separation of the tall element can be variable.

Comment: tl;dr  :-) Maybe you insert a hand-drawn sketch which illustrates what you want to achieve?

Comment: @AlexG done! Check the updated question.